# How can I read Directory and its contents

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having 1 directory and it consists of many folders around 12K + Folders  . Each folder consists two Files:

1) .ini File

2).Xml File .

I want to read all file in 1 shot with bulk insert into Sql Server Table .

Currently I have finished till :

I am able to read particular records from .xml and .ini file and also inserting particular records into sql server .But I want to insert all records in One shot one by one ..

how can i Write a code for bulk record insetion from Windows Directory Folders , and also if a new folder is created it should be automatically inserted into Sql server .

Comment: There are two different questions here. Making a bulk insert of data from folders is easy, but making it automatically insert a new folder into Sql Server is much harder.

Comment: Thank you .Yes, It is difficult But It is Compulsory for Me .Or Can we get Folder property like Folder Creation or updated date of Folder .Please Let me know Atlease Bulk record Insertion .

Answer (score 0):

Implement [IDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.aspx), which will **read** records one-by-one, and pass it to [SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/434atets.aspx) overload. You can do this using iterators and XmlTextReader, to minimize memory usage.

Comment: ,Can Explaint more your Answer /

Comment: @kuldeepverma: you've written, that you can read particular records from files. Now, to use bulk insert, you can wrap you reading code into IDataReader and call corresponding `SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer ` overload.

Comment: :Yes I am trying . If i get Success I ll Let you know.